# Antialiased fonts in emacs 23.2 on Windows

Tags: emacs, winapi, fonts, emacs23

I'm having trouble getting antialiased fonts to work correctly in emacs 23.2, to the extent that it appears that it doesn't actually support antialised fonts.

If I do the following in emacs 23.1:

```
(set-face-font 'default "DejaVu Sans Mono-9.0:antialias=subpixel")
(describe-font nil)
```

Then this reports the full name as "DejaVu Sans Mono-9.0:antialias=subpixel", and the font looks nice and smooth.

However, doing the same thing in emacs 23.2 gives the full name as "DejaVu Sans Mono-9.0" and the font looks nasty and chunky.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've submitted a bug about this: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=6303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug which should be fixed in a future version of emacs; see http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=6303